# jQuery mobile error "cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization"

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically filling a `<ul data-role="listview">` then calling `location.href="#Results"` where the list is, and finally `listview('refresh')`.

All that is done in the success callback of an Ajax request from the same page. It works more or less but I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

I guess jQuery mobile did not construct the listview yet. What could I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html
You have to hook on the pageinit event. You can't call any JQM methods prior to this.
i.e.:

```
$('#Results').bind('pageinit', function() {
  $('#myListview').listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: @user1656416 #Results is the jQuery Mobile page id. More info here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html.

Comment: After trying what was suggested in this error my page now does not show up. It gets rid of the error, but the page i am binding the refresh to will not show.

Answer (score 42):

Just call the listview method without any parameter first:

```
$('#myListview').listview().listview('refresh');
```

Solution taken from http://www.gajotres.net/uncaught-error-cannot-call-methods-on-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-call-method-refresh/

Comment: whoa! worked for me after an hour of banging my head against the wall.

Comment: same for me: in JQM 1.4.5, I tried to create a dynamic popup when clicking on an event in a [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)...
For future users who find this thread: I used the following code

    `eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
         var $popup = $('<div data-role="popup" id="eventPopup">testPopup</div>').appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
      $('#eventPopup').popup().popup("open");
        }`

Comment: @ethanpil and intrixius I'm glad I saved your head from getting major damage. :-)

Comment: wow..this solution also worked on my reflow table woes. `$(".my-table").table().table("refresh");`

Answer (score 28):

you should check if it is already initialized or not, refresh the list in case it is initialized otherwise trigger create as per the following :

```
if ( $('#myListview').hasClass('ui-listview')) {
    $('#myListview').listview('refresh');
     } 
else {
    $('#myListview').trigger('create');
     }
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error. I solved it by adding ":visible" to my query, so it will only run if the list is visible.

So your code will look something like this:

```
$('#myListview:visible').listview('refresh');
```

Worked fine for me!

Comment: Had a problem similar to this one, and you answer help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use  `$.mobile.changePage("#Results");` instead of  `location.href`
actually  `location.href`  reload the page so the list view gets destroy

And then listview.refresh

Comment: This was a really great idea.  Thank you Ashish.

Answer (score 0):

simply add listview.refresh works fine for me,and I'm using ajax to load content into the div too.

```
document.getElementById("myListview").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
//works fine on my work
$('#myListview').listview('refresh');
```

here if my post.

[jquery mobile ajax load content into a div element will lose it's css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706726/jquery-mobile-ajax-load-content-into-a-div-element-will-lose-its-css-style)

I spend almost 3 hours to solve my post probem.finaly find the answer here.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
   $(document).delegate('#Results', 'pageshow', function (){
   $('#mylistview').listview('refresh').trigger('create'); 
   });
```