# jquery mobile ajax load content into a div element will lose it's css style

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

When I'm using ajax to load data into a div element and using `jquery` moible

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="getAjaxContent('recipe')">recipe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="getAjaxContent('sprinkel')">sprinkel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="getAjaxContent('fruit')">fruit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /header -->

<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="main">
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-shop ui-btn-icon-left checkout">checkout</a>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

and I wrote the `javascript` code `getAjaxContentL`

```
function getAjaxContent(type){
var category = type;
console.log("begin to get " + category);

var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

}else{
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
console.log(xmlhttp);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}      
    xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?category="+category,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

and the index.php file is like below:

```
<?php

$category = $_GET['category'];

if($category == recipe){

    echo '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>';

}

if($category == sprinkel){

    echo 'response sprinkel';

}

if($category == fruit){
    echo 'response fruit';

}
```

and it's strange that when I click the recipe it will excute the function `getAjaxContent`.
Also it shows the content in the main div correctly

but the problem is that the element in the main div will lose it's style in jquery mobile.
somebody help??

Comment: What is the response / output of `getAjaxContent`?

Comment: @AxelAmthor it's <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>'

Answer (score 0):

I find the anwser here.

[jquerymobile error "cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373618/jquerymobile-error-cannot-call-methods-on-listview-prior-to-initialization/25707333#25707333)

and it solves my problem .simply add a listview.refresh method