# Why doesn't jQuery-Mobile allow me to call methods of a filterable widget?

Tags: jquery-mobile

It seems that whenever I try to call a method of a filterable widget, such as refresh or destroy, I'm given the error

> Error: cannot call methods on filterable prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'destroy'

[According to the docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#method-destroy), I should be able to use the following format to execute a method on my widget:

```
$( ".selector" ).filterable( "method" );
```

If you go to the filterable demos: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/filterable/, and try to execute the following line

```
$("#filterBasic-input").filterable("destroy")
```

in the browser's console once the page has loaded (presumably, this is a time when the widget is initialized?) you should see the aforementioned error message.

Normally these type of errors occur when trying to call a method inside of the wrong event handler [such as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373618/jquerymobile-error-cannot-call-methods-on-listview-prior-to-initialization?rq=1), but this case is just baffling me completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#filterBasic-input")` is the wrong selector. The filterable widget is actually the list (UL) not the search input box. In your example, give the list an id:

```
<ul id="theList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
```

Then the selector for the filterable widget would be `$("#theList")` e.g.:

```
$("#theList").filterable( "disable" );
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hnq2p8vm/)**